# Do you need to define DbSet's for all entitiies

Tags: entity-framework

I am learning EF and unclear when to create a DbSet for an entity.  In the standard Blog example that the Microsoft Docs have, they define DbSets for both Blog and Post.  Why would one need to create a DbSet for Posts?  Isn't the Posts accessible thru Blogs and therefore I can get the Posts using a LINQ query?

```
public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would one need to create a DbSet for Posts?

It's not strictly necessary.  The rules in EF Core are:

> By convention, types that are exposed in DbSet properties on your
>   context are included in your model. In addition, types that are
>   mentioned in the OnModelCreating method are also included. Finally,
>   any types that are found by recursively exploring the navigation
>   properties of discovered types are also included in the model.

[Including & Excluding Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-types)

But common practice is to declare a DbSet for each Entity because you might want to write a query that starts with Posts, or retrieve a single Post without its associated Blog.